# Can not connect to local repository after data restore

Tags: svn, connection, repository, tortoisesvn, local

I have a local repository in a network drive. It works fine, but I have a HDD problem when I connect it to a router, and the HDD went to raw format. After that I can restore all files in HDD with a recovery software. Recover was correct I think. Every files seems to be OK.

But now I can not connect to the repository, can not browse etc. When I try to commit something:

```
unable to connect to a repository at url: file:///Z:/wt/trunk/   
unable to open repository
```

Repo files are available in that location, when I see in file manager. Location path is the same before the HDD problem. Everything seems to be OK (Repo size, repo structure /conf, db, hooks/ ), but it doesn't work. I think it is just a checksum error or something like this.

Is there any tool to repair the repo, or find the problem with it?

My Tortoise SVN version is 1.9.7 64 bit.

Comment: What contents do you see in Z:\wt\ and Z:\wt\trunk?

Comment: I see the 3 folder in Z:\wt (conf, db, hook) In db folder: (revs, transaction folders + 2 file) In revs folder ("0" folder inside this the revision files about 200 files 4,7 gb) In transaction folder (a lot of another folder) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make backups! Do not rely on data recovery software - it does not guarantee that the recovered data is bit to bit equivalent to the data you lost.

When you can access the repository directory with File Explorer at `Z:\wt\` and see [`conf/ db/ hooks/` directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.basics.html) at al it does not mean that the repository is in working state. You need to run `svnadmin verify Z:\wt\` and see whether the repository is consistent and healthy or not. If the verification finishes without any errors - you are in luck.

If the repository is consistent, then the `svn info file:///Z:/wt/trunk/` should work without any errors. If you still see errors, show the exact and complete wording of the error message and check whether the `file://` URL that you use is correct.

Comment: svnadmin verify Z:\wt\ command send me the following error: **svnadmin: E720002: Can't open file 'Z:\wt\format':**  svn info file:///Z:/wt/trunk/ command send **svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///Z:/wt/trunk'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///Z:/wt/trunk**

Comment: @Sancho79 the repository is corrupted and requires manual repair. I don't think that you will repair or restore it without a backup. In other words, your data recovery software did not fully recover the repository and its data.

Comment: Working copy with that hidden .svn folder is not enought to repair the repository? This hidden .svn folder is about 2,43 Gb. Is not contain any useable information?

Comment: @Sancho79 the working copy can help you recover only the data that's stored in this working copy, it will not help you recover version history that was stored in the repository. You can create a new empty repository and `svn import` the contents of the working copy to this repository (import everything except `.svn` directory).

Comment: I will create a new empty repository and import all of the working directory data to it. After this operation, conncection beetween the working copy and the old damaged repository will end? Or firstly do I have to delete the .svn directory to break old connection?

Comment: Just checkout a new working copy after you import the data into the new repository. Make sure that you do not commit the `.svn` directory when you import the data.

Comment: Ok. Understand everything. Thanks for your help! :) For other users who read this => DON'T FORGET TO BACKUP YOUR REPOSITORY!